# Readonly property on Field SenchaTouch

Tags: field, sencha-touch, readonly

Hi i've been looking for the readOnly property for field in secnhatouch but haven't found it... can some one assist me on this matter

```
{
                 xtype: 'textfield',
                 name: 'ReferenceNumber',
                 readOnly:true,
                 label: 'Reference'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want the disabled field

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    name: 'ReferenceNumber',
    **disabled**: true,
    value: '12312421',
    label: 'Reference'
}
```

I  overload the 'disabledCls' because it grey's out the label more than i want.

Comment: actually you were right when the fields gets rendered on mobile device the afterrender listener does not work...

Answer (score 8):

I ran into the same problem with `readOnly: true` not working - I was able to fix it by adding an `afterrender` listener:

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    name: 'ReferenceNumber',
    label: 'Reference',
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function(ele) {
            ele.fieldEl.dom.readOnly = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: definitly the answer i was looking for

Comment: @Nick. When the fields gets rendered on mobile device the afterrender listener does not work..How you fix this if you need anytime again after screen is rendered?

Comment: In Sencha 2.3.1 I have used `listeners:{ focus:function(cmp) { cmp.getComponent().input.dom.readOnly = cmp.config.readOnly; } }`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by setting `readOnly: null` or `readOnly: undefined`:

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    name: 'Website',
    label: 'Website',
    readOnly: null
}
```